# How to redeliver queued messages in RabbitMQ using Langohr?

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, amqp, langohr

**Background**

We consume messages from RabbitMQ with Langohr (version 3.4.0) and try to persist them into MongoDB. We're not using `auto-ack` since if we fail to persist the messages in MongoDB we want to be able to retry later. We're using the [ack-unless-exception](http://reference.clojurerabbitmq.info/langohr.consumers.html)
 function to accommodate this. Tonight MongoDB had a temporary disruption and was down for a short period of time during which 40 messages couldn't be persisted and were thus retained in the RabbitMQ queue. But when MongoDB came back up again our Langohr handler just received new messages. The old ones were not delivered to us before we did a restart of our application.

**Question**

How can we make RabbitMQ redeliver the previous nack:ed messages with Langohr without having to restart our application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undelivered messages are not automatically redelivered. You want to take a look at 
[recover](http://reference.clojurerabbitmq.info/langohr.basic.html#var-recover). This method will signal to RabbitMQ that is has to redeliver unprocessed messages. When you do this is depending on your architecture

Comment: Is this needed even "langohr.core/automatic-recovery-enabled?" is true?

Comment: according to http://clojurerabbitmq.info/articles/error_handling.html , this works only on transport layer (TCP connection). So a TCP connection between client and the queue has to be disrupted before the recovery is triggered. In the OP case, that connection was fine